# Sympathy Vote - what published studies exist?

Tags: election, political-science

Is there academic rigour around what defines a sympathy vote, and what magnitude of an effect has on elections?

Are there classifications for sympathetic events? What sympathetic factors drive the election outcome - distance from the election, number of opponents, level of undecided voters, extent of media coverage, levels of favourables and unfavourables, etc?

Does the Sympathy Vote affect others by association - for example, other members of the same political party?